# How to use Facebook Sharer in PHP

Tags: php, facebook

Am I missing something? I use this simple code

```
<a name="fb_share" type="button" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=123.abc.comt=TEst">share on Facebook</a>
```

and the content that is being shared is blank? Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're missing the ampersand ('&') in your url:

```
<a name="fb_share" type="button" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=123.abc.com&t=TEst">share on Facebook</a>
```

Comment: still nothing changed. i want to share a page. but change the content in the share option using facebook sharer. but the one that is being shared is the page where Im at. what do i have to do

Answer (score 5):

The Share button is no longer deprecated and has made a come back as share dialogue:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/share-links/

On sites like buzzfeed.com their share buttons are still an important source of referral.

Comment: Looks like they no longer support `t=` though?

Comment: @ChuckLeButt Yup. You cannot add Text now

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the sharer, it has been deprecated and is no longer supported:

> The Share button has been deprecated in favor of the Like button, and
>   will no longer be supported.
>   Please use the Like button whenever
>   possible to drive maximum traffic to your apps.

(http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/)

> **What happened to the old Share button?**
>
> We deprecated the Share Button when we launched the Like button,
>   because the Like button improves clickthrough rates by allowing users
>   to connect with one click, and by allowing them to see which of their
>   friends have already connected.

(http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

Comment: if im going to use that. how can I change the facebook share content?

Comment: Well, your code looks legit I think, make sure that you have the full url (including `http`) and that it's url encoded, like in the example in the documentation: `http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sadtrombone.com%2F&t=Sad%20Trombone`. But since it's not supported yet, it can behave strangely and there's not much you can do about that other than the right thing which is to stop using it. Why would you want to use deprecated, unsupported feature? It's a very bad practice.

Comment: If I use the like button instead of facebook sharer. how can i change the content of the share option?

Comment: Just use the `Step 1 - Get Like Button Code` section in the Like button documentation page, then click the `Get Code` button. You can specify the url to "like".

Comment: i mean the content of the facebook share itself. i want to change it.

Comment: You need to use the open graph meta tags to define the title, image, description of the page.

Comment: This is great advice in theory, but in practice: the deprecation happened in 2011, at this time there's still no warning of when it might actually be removed, its use remains widespread, and a lot of people still prefer sharer.php and there aren't any signs it is about to disappear.  Feed Dialog doesn't have the "On your own timeline / on a friend's timeline / in a private Message" dropdown, which some people find convenient.  As long as one has a backup strategy to switch to in case disaster strikes and is able to release updated code fast, I don't see why not to use it.

Comment: There's still benefits to using share over like/send or the feed dialog. Items posted using share seem to have a higher ranking under "top stories". Shared items have larger images than liked or feed dialog posts. Send only goes to a friend's mailbox while share can post to their wall. Share can also post to page.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, Its simple, What ever page you want to share, Just put it after u=
Any link after that will be shared on facebook, If the link page has og:meta-tags, og:image, og:title and og:decription, It will also be shared of that page making it interactive :)

Comment: can you tell me my sharer is not working as expected: http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://pythonthusiast.pythonblogs.com/230_pythonthusiast/archive/1371_python_for_beginner_1__get_to_know_what_this_is_all_about.html