# Facebook app Id for WordPress Plugin development

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I'm building a small social WP plugin (more for learning purposes than anything else) and I'm trying to get my head around the various social networking sharing api's etc.

With regards to Facebook sharing, there seems to be the requirement for an application ID.  Thats easy enough if this a one time thing, on a single site, but in the case of writing a plugin, I obviously would want it to be easy for users to install and setup, and not neccessarily have every user have to put one in from an options panel.

It seems to work when removing it from the FB.init, though I'm developing locally, and get an error when trying to use the like button.

Is an APP ID 100% required?  and if so can I as a plugin author use one (think this gets paired with a website URL so not sure if its even possible) or the plugin that would

Anyone experienced with this got any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using the feed dialog, you do need an App (with ID). But you can - of course - just use your own App and just put it in the plugin. The App ID is nothing secret, and with that way you can also monitor the usage with the Facebook Insights.

There is one option without the feed dialog: sharer.php

It is exlained here: [How to use Facebook Sharer in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186852/how-to-use-facebook-sharer-in-php)

Just keep in mind that it is deprecated though (see other thread).

Comment: thanks for the concise answer, The deprecation of the sharer.php was the beginning of my woes, or rather the beginning of me taking a serious look at all of this, which ultimately will be a good thing for me and clients I suppose.  Maybe then I should look to include an option, (ie: use my facebook app ID by default - or use your own), as you mentioned the app ID is linked to your insights, which might annoy users who do know about it.

Comment: can you not use the feed dialog though?

Comment: sure, but not without an app, see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'm gonna go the route of using a standard app, and allow users to switch it out for there own if they want to.  Hmmm, dynamic PHP and javascript in WP, I feel another question brewing, but that should be a good lot of fun to play with.