# How can I add a custom styled Facebook like / share button on an input-field?

Tags: facebook, button, input, facebook-like

I don't want to use the normal Facebook like button so how can I add a like / share button to a -Field?

Comment: can you specify your qestion a little bit: How do you implement your button and where it is? which instruments do you use to make your button?

Answer (score 2):

It is not allowed to use a custom styled like button, see Brand Permissions:

https://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/

https://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php

You can only use a custom graphic for sharing, but in your case it would be more appropriate to use a share function anyway (the Twitter button is also for sharing).
See here: [How to use Facebook Sharer in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186852/how-to-use-facebook-sharer-in-php)

...or use the JavaScript SDK of facebook with the FB.ui function. But in that case you would need an app too.