# How do I create a custom Like button for my web app?

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like, custom-controls

Flipboard (ios/Android) has a Facebook "Like" button which Im trying to emulate but do not know where to start?  [image: Flipboard Facebook LIKE]

I was thinking to place a image on top of the generic "like" button using CSS. Anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You generally shouldn't do that (change the visual aspect of the like button)
The answer in this thread is pretty accurate : [Custom styled facebook like button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431249/how-can-i-add-a-custom-styled-facebook-like-share-button-on-an-input-field?rq=1)

What you could do is create a Facebook app for your site, ask for user authorization when the user triggers one of your sharing feature and post open-graph stories to Facebook.

That way you would have a much bigger inventory of options that are much more "hip and catchy" than plain likes (I would keep the generic like button in there too anyways) AND you keep complete control over the visuals.