# Facebook share callback to know shared or not

Tags: facebook, share

I am using a facebook sharer link to let users share a link:

http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=www.blablabla.com

Is there a way, such as a callback, I can know whether the user actually shared the link or not? For example I am able to put a script on www.blablabla.com to receive the callback.

By the way the parameter "t" for title is deprecated? Seems not working now.

Comment: You should use the facebook like button. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11186953/2358467